# react-native-gifted-chat How to display user avatar as user's initial if image is null

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

setup
Expo
react native
Gifted-chat

Question
In chat screen , I want to display initial of user's name (other than the current user) if the the user has no image for avatar.
I dont know how to use or which props to use.

Can anyone please help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by following config:

Message object-->
user: {
_id: database_user_sender,
avatar: Avatar_Image?
Avatar_Image :
`https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0dbc3f&color=FFF&name=${FirstName_LastName}`
},